# Как получить куки,который httponly

Tags: c#, cookie, httpclient

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как бы вот тут куки есть `ASP.NET` он с параметром httponly

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут уже нету. Куки контейнер этот кук тоже не ловит, может я должен добавить в парметры httpclient что-либо, чтобы httponly куки тоже ловил?
Или как мне его поймать?

Comment: Вопрос нужно задавать текстом, а не скриншотами.

Comment: Как вариант - можешь попробовать вручную достать их из заголовков ответа. Пример: https://gist.github.com/mt89vein/9c9d7291d42dac0d1598f1a61da3117c

Comment: А если я вам скажу, что [не воспроизводится](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ks8fAl)?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ почему вы потом запрос на куки, делаете к baseaddres? Он изменяется после запроса, или в него куки идут?

Comment: @SultanovShamil я и так и так брал, в заголовках тоже нету данной куки

Comment: Куки привязываются к домену, а не к адресу, по этому и ищутся они через этот самый базовый домен. Посмотрите что вам дает PostMan, столбец `Domain`, вот он и является решающим для поиска.